# What is this underground giant creature?

Tags: monsters, dungeons-and-dragons, content-identification

Every once in a while i remember reading about an underground (underdark?) creature that had somewhat following qualities:

- giant that lives underground
- it was very ugly and was extremely hunched to fit in the caves
- it had the ability straighten itself up, that granted it great bonuses, if the surroundings allowed it such a thing. I recall there being a bonuses to con and str, possibly size/reach increases.
- i read the creature entry from a book, so it wasnt a situation on the table that DM made up.

Id like to know the book it is from, edition it is from, it's name and the special quality details of this creature.

Comment: Are you certain of the standing advantages being CON, STR and SIZE, REACH? If so, that would point towards 4e or 5e as earlier edition monsters didn't get statted like players, and SIZE/REACH mechanics pretty much were non-existent.

Comment: It might've been a bonus to damage and hit, either way. Its been years since I've seen it. Not at all sure about size and reach. But there definately was a "unhunching" ability that made encounter more dangerous.

Comment: @Erics Not true.  Even 1e AD&D monsters have 'size' as a stat.  And 3.0 is when monsters started having ability scores, not 4e.

Comment: Read  about in what?

Answer (score 3):

I cannot find a creature with the ability to straighten itself up to grant bonuses, but the Phaerlin Giant fits the physical description of your creature.

---

## Phaerlin Giant

> **Special Attacks:** Frightful presence
> **Special Qualities:** Scent, SR 14
> **Feats:** Cleave, Power Attack
>
> Formed from stone giants warped by powerful magic, phaerlin giants are a savage slave race found in the Underdark.
> Phaerlin giants would be 20 feet tall if they could stand up straight, but their bodies are stooped and hunched. They use their hands when walking and they are clumsy with weapons and held items. Their features are bestial as well--their jaws protrude and their teeth are sharp and elongated. Their hairless skin is incredibly tough, and their backs are covered with hard plates reminiscent of a beholder's hide. Their eyes are yellow and watery, and their ears are tiny.

*p. 50-51, Monster Compendium: Monsters of Faerûn, 3rd Edition*

Comment: It's possible that the DM extrapolated the "if they could stand up" bonus.

Comment: I've read them from a book, it never was a situation on the table.

Comment: It really depends a lot on the word "book". Book about what? I'm not saying I'm sure it was a Phaerlin Giant that you read about, but in adventure modules (which are books) usually the DM (that is, the book writer) included additional details on how to use monsters/situations, for all those DM too stupid/lazy/RAW to come up with obvious things themselves. The description of the giant clearly calls for "it could really use a higher ceiling", and

Comment: any half decent DM would have one chasing the party trough a really narrow corridor (where the party is protected, but can't fight it properly) to a wide cavern where they suddenly feel advantaged by being able to spread around it, just for the giant standing up a couple rounds later and evening the odds again